# Share static library memory with dll

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm making game in c++ and trying to make it moddable by loading .dll using LoadLibrary().
Both, exe and dll are using the same engine.lib. And i want to share the same memory of engine.lib for exe and dll, because setting static member variables manually is really annoying. Is it even posible to implement something like this with runtime linking?

Edit:
I solved it thanks to Chris Loonam's comment by switching from static library to dynamic library

Comment: *"Both, exe and dll are using the same engine.lib."* - No, they are not. Assuming that *engine.lib* is indeed a static library, each module gets their own *copy*. If you want to share code and data between modules, each module will have to link against the same DLL.

Comment: By same engine.lib i meant, same file because if it was like absolutely same, there would be no reason to write this question

Comment: The reason you are asking this question is, because you do not [understand the classical model for linking](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130107-00/?p=5633).